# От цикла do while к while

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток. Есть код, который я сильно упростил, но суть не поменялась. Вот:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM table ORDER BY field LIMIT 0, 5",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do { printf ("<table><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table>", $myrow["code"]; }
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

Записей 5, все супер. Переделываю на:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM table ORDER BY field LIMIT 0, 5",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ printf ("<table><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table>", $myrow["code"]; }
```

Записей становится 4. "кэп фшоке", я тоже.

- из за чего такое может быть? O_o

З.Ы. весь посторонний код со страницы, на которой запрос, я убрал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо заменить

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM table ORDER BY field LIMIT 0, 5",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
     printf ("<table><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table>", $myrow["code"]; 
}
```

на

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM table ORDER BY field LIMIT 0, 5",$db);       
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
     printf ("<table><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table>", $myrow["code"]; 
}
```

Comment: спасибо. буду внимательнее. решение оказалось безумно простым )

Answer (score 3):

Вы выдираете из результата 5 массивов, а выводите только 4:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM table ORDER BY field LIMIT 0, 5",$db);
//$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);  <- убираем, ибо смысла сие делать уже нету
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    printf ("<table><tr><td>%s</td></tr></table>", $myrow["code"]; 
}
```